cannot create subdomain because dns client is nil
when I deploy from docker registry app (abdomamdouh/kiada:0.1) to k3s cluster using porter.run text, I get this error

my porter config cluster: 4 driver: local helmrepo: "0" host: http://localhost:8081 project: 1 registry: 1 token: ""
thank you I want solve this problem.
